# Does generically finite imply quasi-finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of $k$-varieties ($k$ a field, characteristic 0 or even algebraically closed if it matters), and $f$ is dominant and generically finite, then is $f$ quasi-finite? By quasi-finite I mean that for each $y \in Y$ $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite.

Comment: Think about blowing up a point on $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $Bl_{(0,0)} \Bbb A^2\to \Bbb A^2$, the blowup of the origin in $\Bbb A^2$. This is an isomorphism on $\Bbb A^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ but has a whole $\Bbb P^1$ over the origin.

Comment: Ah I see, that was easy, thank you.

Comment: @Dcoles if this answers your question, please accept the answer via the green checkmark on the left.